# How to build a project in qt 5.2.1 for amd64 (setup cl.exe and missing mspdb110.dll file)?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I have installed qt 5.2.1 and Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 7 x64 (I have codepage 1251 if it matters). I use vs11 compiler.

Firstly I tried to run 'Rebuild all' action and I have received an error connected with cl.exe.

Then I added the path to vs11/bin to PATH variable (where cl.exe file is located; strange but it is in Program Files x86 folder) and have received the error: mspdb110.dll is missing. What should I do next? How to build the project?

Answer (score 0):

Add to PATH path of directory with this dll. It's in something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64`. If you have not such file in entire system, I guess you should reinstall Visual Studio.